# nginx configuration: one location with different server IP

Tags: nginx, server, location

I have the main app running on a server with IP 127.0.0.1 and the domain is `http://myexample.com`.

I want to add another service to the app with the url `http://myexample.com/service`.

However, the service is running on another server with IP 127.0.0.2 with port 5000.

How to make nginx configuration work in this situation?

What I have tried is as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myexample.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
    }
    location /service {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:5000;
    }
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

when I open myexample.com/service, it returns 404 or 500.

Comment: The Nginx config should work. Is your app listening on port 5000 on 127.0.0.2? Is Nginx (or a different web server) configured to listen on that port? Also, is comms on that port allowed through the firewall on the other server?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence yes, the other app is listening on port 5000 on 127.0.0.2. How to check whether through firewall is allowed? 
However, I used `<iframe>` to make it work for me now. Thanks very much